# JSpinner en Java

Tags: java

Alguien me puede ayudar y explicarme que significa este código en JAVA sobre el componente Jspinner.

```
Integer valor = (Integer)miJSpinner.getValue();
```

¿Por qué se coloca integer antes del control mijSpinner?, ¿qué hace `getvalue`?

```
int valor;
valor= (int) jSpinner1.getValue();
```

¿Por qué se coloca int antes del control jSpinner1?

Comment: No soy usuario de Java, pero ahi estas obteniendo el valor de la variable JSpinner y le estas haciendo un Cast a int, osea convertis ese valor al tipo de valor int (numerico)

Answer (score 1):

El método `getValue()` de la clase `JSpinner` simplemente delega su cometido al modelo, es decir, que hacer `jSpinner.getValue()` es equivalente a hacer `jSpinner.getModel().getValue()`.

Tanto `JSpinner::getValue()` como `SpinnerModel::getValue()` tienen en su definición que devuelven Object. **Pero hay que recordar que si un método devuelve un objeto, ese objeto puede ser de la clase indicada o de cualquiera de sus descendientes**. Por lo que si el método devuelve Object, pudiera devolver un String, un Integer, un Long, o cualuier otro objeto cuya clase que herede de Object.

En este caso `SpinnerModel::getValue()` indica que devuelve un `Object` en su definición pero realmente recibimos un `Integer`. ¿Por qué recibimos ese `Integer`?

Si has instanciado el `JSpinner` sin ningún parámetro es decir:

```
JSpinner jSpinner = new JSPinner();
```

el constructor crea un `JSpinner` con un modelo de tipo `SpinnerNumberModel`. El código del constructor es este:

```
public JSpinner() {
    this(new SpinnerNumberModel());
}
```

Internamente `SpinnerNumberModel` tiene un atributo llamado `value` de tipo `Number` para guardar ese valor. Igualmente, si se inicializa el `SpinnerNumberModel` sin parámetros, por defecto lo que se guarda en esos `Number` son enteros. El código es algo así:

```
public class SpinnerNumberModel extends AbstractSpinnerModel implements Serializable {

   private Number value;

   public SpinnerNumberModel() {
      this(new Integer(0), null, null, new Integer(1));
   }

   public SpinnerNumberModel(Number value, Comparable minimum, Comparable maximum, Number stepSize) {
      [...]
      this.value = value;
      [...]
   }

   public Object getValue() {
      return value;
   }

}
```

Fíjate que en el constructor si no se indican parámetros, lo que hace es llamar al otro constructor con value = 0 (entero). Por lo que en el atributo value lo que hay es un Integer.

Por lo que al crear el JSpinner sin parámetros, se crea un SpinnerNumberModel de enteros, así que cuando se llama a `getValue()` nos devuelve un entero.

Como el método `getValue()` dice que devuelve Object pero sabemos que realmente hay un `Integer` en esa variable, le hacemos el cast.

```
Integer valor = (Integer) jSpinner.getValue();
```

Si no hiciesemos el cast, tendríamos un `Object` y con un `Object` no podríamos hacer operaciones que podríamos hacer con un `Integer`, por ejemplo sumar el valor, multiplicarlo, etc. Ejemplo:

```
Object obj1 = jSpinner1.getValue();
Objetc obj2 = jSpinner2.getValue();
int resultado = obj1 + obj2; // Error: No se pueden sumar objects
```

Más info:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#getValue()
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerModel.html#getValue()
- https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/javax/swing/JSpinner.java
- http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel-source.html